# SharpPcap get Process Name

Tags: c#

i'm currently writing a C# program which has similar features as wireshack, using the SharpPcap to capture the packets and PacketDotNet to get the information about the packet. I would like to know how can i get the name of the process associated with the packet??

Comment: Please include some sample code to help explain the issue!

Answer (score 2):

You can get `ProcessId` by parsing the output from `netstat -o` and then get **process name** from `Process.GetById`.
May be this code will be helpful, but i'm not very strong with regexps :)

```
  var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
      FileName = "netstat",
      Arguments = "-on",
      UseShellExecute = false,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      CreateNoWindow = true
    }
  };

  proc.Start();
  Regex r = new Regex(@"\S+\s+(?<address>\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<pid>\d+)");
  while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    var res = r.Match(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    if (res.Success) {
      var pid = int.Parse(res.Groups["pid"].Value);
      var address = res.Groups["address"].Value;
      Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", address, Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this really the only option?  I don't suppose this will work very well when determining which browser is using port 80?

Comment: Can't say for sure but I think you can also try to use [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) which has graphic interface and also command line tool that are very similar to netstat